# Reducing the time complexity

Tags: c, algorithm, big-o

The question asked is using

```
struct match_score
{
char country[20];
int score;
};
```

wherein the structure is related to a batsman's score and the country he scored against.
We have  to find the country against which he has the highest average.

I have written a code whose time complexity is O(n^2)
Can anyone suggest me how to reduce the time complexity to O(nlogn) or O(n)

Code with O(n^2)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct match_score
{ 
  char country[20];
  int score;
};
char *func(struct match_score *array,int len); 
main()
{
    struct match_score scores[]={
        {"Pakistan",23},
        {"India",52},
        {"Pakistan",40},
        {"India",22},
        {"Australia",80}
    };
    char *max_avg=func(scores,5);
    printf("%s",max_avg);

}
char *func(struct match_score *array,int len)
{

 int i,j,average[20],avg,l,max=0,max_num;
 char co[20];
 for(i=0;i<len;i++)
 {
     average[i]=0;
 }
 for(i=0;i<len;i++)
 {
      avg=0;
      l=0;
      strcpy(co,"");
      strcpy(co,array[i].country);
      for(j=0;j<len;j++)
      {
          if(strcmp(array[j].country,co)==0)
          {
              l++;
              avg+=array[j].score;
          } 
      }
      average[i]=avg/l;
   }

   for(i=0;i<len;i++)
   {
      if(average[i]>max)
      {
         max=average[i];
         max_num=i;
      }
   }
   for(i=0;i<len;i++)
   {
      printf("%d %d\n",i,average[i]);
   }
   return array[max_num].country;
}
```

Comment: what is the exact question? what do you need to find out here?

Comment: For such a question you should explain your current algorithm and why you are using it.

Comment: In first place, do something more meaningful, like removing the superfluous `strcpy(co,"");` call and use initialization instead of the "zero-out-in-for-loop" at the beginning...

Comment: I'm really sorry but im a begginer .

Comment: The question is to return the name of the country against which the batsman has scored consistently(Highest average)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The area where you hit n^2 is here;

```
 for(i=0;i<len;i++)
 {
      for(j=0;j<len;j++)
      {
          if(strcmp(array[j].country,co)==0)
```

All this is doing is searching for duplicate countries in your array.  If you sort the array, at a cost of n log n, you can find duplicates in order n.  This leaves you with a new complexity of o(n log n)

Comment: Does qsort(library function) give complexity of O(nlogn)?

Comment: @Gerrard8 qsort has average case complexity O(nlgn) worst case O(n^2). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Answer (score 1):

You could use a temporary collection in which you store the averages, then iterate over that to find the largest. This will use more space, but will be O(2n) as you have to loops in a row instead of nested.

Comment: Could you please elaborate.How can i do that with only one loop.In python i can use dictionary and do it but in c what do i do?  One more thing im not allowed to make changes in structure format.Thank You

Comment: @Gerrard8 You could use a structure that contains the information for calculating averages (total, count and current average) and store that in a hash-table (or similar) indexed by the country name. Then you use one loop to add countries to this hash-table, as well as calculating the averages. Then a new loop to find the country with the largest average. Or instead of having a hash-table, some kind of list where you keep the largest average at the head of the list.

Answer (score -1):

If you sort the arry, your complicaation reduce significanty. searching a number in a sorted
arry is much quicker....

Btw, you should have explained your algorithem and your code, or at least give some notes...

Comment: I'm really sorry.Im a beginner and new to stackoverflow